# Second level lookup with SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How do I write a SQL statement that does a second level lookup only if first is not matched. For example:

In the below query, if my `SEDOLCode` condition does not return a record, proceed to lookup with condition 2 with RICCode.

```
 select 
     *, GETDATE()
 from 
     Securities sec
 where
     sec.SEDOLCode = 'ABCDEF'
     or sec.RICCode = '002815.SZ'
```

This query is returning two different records - for example:

```
1234    ABCDEF  DUMY906.X
5675    EFTFS   002815.SZ
```

I am taking data from a file to update the `Price`table as below. I want to use `SedolCode` as primary lookup.

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   INSERT INTO dbo.Price (sec.SecurityID, ClosingPrice, UpdatedDate, UpdatedByUser, Priced)
       SELECT 
           ..., GETDATE()
       FROM
           Securities sec
       WHERE 
           sec.SEDOLCode = @SedolCode
           OR sec.RICCode = @RicCode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this the logic is basically if the sedolcode is found then it will only meet the first condition. Otherwise the count of that sedolcolde will be 0 and it will look at riccode.

```
 select 
     *, GETDATE()
 from 
     Securities sec
 where
   sec.sedolcode = 'ABCDEF'
   OR ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM securites WHERE sedolcode ='ABCDEF') = 0 AND sec.riccode = '002815.SZ')
```

Comment: Is this in where clause? Can you use my existing code to show answer please ?

Comment: @user2781389 Modified the answer. Yes it was just use the where clause from mine and copy it to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - reminds me of my FTSE days........
Match Sedol and Not Ric
or
Ric and Not Sedol and use myOrdering & TOP to get the first.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Price
(
    sec.SecurityID
    , ClosingPrice
    , UpdatedDate
    , UpdatedByUser
    , Priced
)
SELECT TOP 1 [specifiy fields to insert]
FROM        
(
        select 1 as myOrdering ...
            , GETDATE()
        from Securities sec
        WHERE 
          (sec.RICCode = @RicCode AND sec.SEDOLCode != @SedolCode)
        UNION
        select 2 as myOrdering ...
            , GETDATE()
        from Securities sec
        WHERE 
          (sec.RICCode = @RicCode AND sec.SEDOLCode != @SedolCode)
)SUB_Q ORDER BY myOrdering
```